# What does the notation inf{...} mean?

Tags: notation, supremum-and-infimum

I came across

$$\inf\{k : f \in C^k\}$$

What does $\inf\{\cdot\}$ mean? I have been looking, but haven't found anything.

Comment: It means infimum.

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense in this particular context, since if $f$ is $\mathcal C^k$ for _any one_ $k$, then it is also $\mathcal C^0$, so this infimum is either $0$ or (perhaps) $\infty$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means infimum. So, $\inf\{\ldots\}$ is the infimum of the set $\{\ldots\}$ (assuming that it is a non-empty set of real numbers with a lower bound).

Comment: To save a google search: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum

Comment: This answer is a bit like Q “what does etc. mean” being answered with “etc. means et cetera.”  I.e. factually correct but not really what the OP was seeking. If the OP knew what infimum was they would know what inf meant.

Answer (score 20):

Suppose that you have a non-empty set of numbers,as an example $A = \{1,10,\pi,55, 11.2, \sqrt{2}, {1\over 2}\}$ then the *infinium* of this set is the greatest lower bound of the set. In this simple case $$\inf\{A\}={1\over 2}$$

As an added bonus: what you gave us $$\inf\{k: f\in C^k\}$$ means that, given a function $f$ differentiable $n$ times, the infimum is the lower possible $k$ such that the $k$-th derivative of this function is continuous. But I think that $k$ will be $0$ every time..

Comment: "lower upper bound"??

Comment: Oops, my bad, I'm correcting it

Comment: Maybe you meant not "infinium" but "infimum" and not "lower bound" but "greatest lower bound"

Comment: Thank you all, I wrote the answer quickly! Now it's all corrected

Comment: And by axiom,  every non empty down bounded set of real numbers has infimum...

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it's clear, concrete, and rich. Still, it's difficult when applying the concept to a new scenario. For example, does inf{$x$: $F_X{(x)}$ $\ge$ $y$} mean the lowest value of $x$ such that $F_X{(x)}$ $\ge$ $y$, @DavideMorgante?

Answer (score 6):

Lower bound of some set of numbers is number which smaller or equal to any  number of the set.
Greatest lower bound of some set of numbers is a number which is a lower bound of the set and is bigger or equal to any other lower bound of the set. $\inf A$ means greatest lower bound of the set $A$. So e.g. $\inf A = 5$ means greatest lower bound of the set $A$ is $5$.
Greatest lower bound is also called infimum.